# ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario termine este programa a voluntad? (Darle opción)

Tags: c++

Tengo este programa que simula la reserva de boletos de avión con unos números random al inicio para hacer como si otras personas ya hubieran reservado boletos antes del usuario.

Me gustaría permitirle al usuario que pueda terminar el programa en el momento que lo desee, ya que este se ejecuta de manera infinita si no existe esta opción para el usuario.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 1, fila, columna,columnar,columnar1,columnar2,columnar3,columnar4;
    int asiento[2][10] = {0};

    srand (time(NULL));
    columnar = rand () % 10 + 1;
    columnar1 = rand () % 10 + 1;
    columnar2 = rand () % 10 + 1;
    columnar3 = rand () % 10 + 1;
    columnar4 = rand () % 10 + 1;

    cout<<"¡Bienvenido! A continuación realizarás tu reserva de boletos"<<endl;

    while( c <= 10){

        do
{
    cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-2)"<<endl;
    cin >> fila;
}
while( fila > 2 || fila > 2 ); 

        cout << endl;

        do
{
    cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de columna (1-10)"<<endl;
    cin >> columna;
}
while( columna > 10 || columna > 10 ); 

        if(columna==columnar){
            cout << endl;
            cout<<"¡Asiento ocupado!";
        }else

        if(asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] == 0){
            asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] = 1;
            c = c +1;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "¡Reserva exitosa!";
        }else
        cout << "¡Asiento ocupado!";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        cout << asiento[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Como pueden ver en los primeros "cout" entre paréntesis aparecen los rangos de números que le debería permitir al usuario (ya que los asientos no pueden ser infinitos) pero no los respeta y acepta cualquier numero.

Supongamos que tu idea es que se repita el mensaje hasta que el usuario introduzca un valor válido...

- se repita el mensaje -> necesitamos un bucle
- hasta que el usuario introduzca un valor válido -> condición para abandonar el bucle

Dicho con código:

```
do
{
    cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-2)"<<endl;
    cin >> fila;
}
while( fila == 1 || fila == 1 );
```

> De igual manera me gustaría encontrar una manera de que el usuario pueda terminar de forma voluntaria el programa ya que este sigue preguntando por números de asiento de forma infinita.

Formas hay miles, por ejemplo:

```
if(asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] == 0){
    asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] = 1;
    c = c +1;
    cout << "Reserva exitosa " <<endl;

    cout << "Deseas hacer otra reserva? (s/n)";
    char respuesta;
    std::cin >> respuesta;
    if( respuesta == 's' || respuesta == 'S' )
        break; // abandonamos el bucle while
}else
```

Comment: Gracias, pude implementar el primer código al programa y funcionó perfecto. Pero no pude encontrar la manera de implementar el segundo pedazo para que el usuario termine el programa voluntariamente.

Comment: @Myth el segundo código tenía una pequeña errata... pero no entiendo que no pudieses hacerlo funcionar... puesto donde se indica funciona sin más